# How to handle multiple api endpoints for apollo iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apollo

The client has 2 api endpoints. Endpoints is for getting a token which endpoints use to authenticate before fetching information.

Following the instruction on Apollo I have managed to create the API package for the first endpoints which I succeed to implement getting the token. However, I am at a loss how to integrate the second endpoints schema into the current projects.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/tutorial/tutorial-add-graphql-schema
The tutorial above show how to create apollo-codegen-config.json to fetch the schema then run
./apollo-ios-cli generate to generate a package. However, If I have 2 schema when I try to run the generate command it would give the error

```
GraphQLSchemaValidationError-There can be only one directive named "@apollo_client_ios_localCacheMutation".

There can be only one directive named "@import".

There can be only one type named "Query".-GraphQLSchemaValidationError@
@
@
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.